# Is there a way that I can check the syntax of HTML with C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, html-parsing

I have an editing window that allows my authorized users to enter in HTML which is then stored in a database after they click submit. Unfortunately it is something like this:

```
<ul class="controls-buttons">
         <li class="sep"></li>
     <li id="home">
<a title="Home" <a="" data-href="x">xx</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Is there a way that I can check the HTML string before storing it in the database to ensure it is valid HTML markup? For example here note the use of `<a` and `<a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the fragment into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (an HTML parser). The source download contains many example projects showing usage.

Check the `ParseErrors` property to see if the fragment is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks but I wonder if this is a bit more than I need. Also I am concerned it's not a Microsoft supported library. Some of the comments I saw suggested people were having problems. Is there some other way using a Microsoft library. All I really need to do is to check that all the tags match up. And that a user does not input something like in my example.

Comment: @Anne - If you want to parse HTML, this is one of the best tools out there. It is widely used. Not sure what this concern about it not being from Microsoft is - they are not the be all and end all of software. In regards to matching tags up - this is still a good solution for HTML.

Comment: I will look into this more. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Your next best approach would be to use C# and .NET with the Regex object. Simply use a regular expression that meets your requirements and validate content against your regular expression.

Comment: Honestly that sounds almost impossible :-(

Comment: You really need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) to see why regex is **not** suitable for validating unknown HTML.

Comment: While it is true that asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking Paris Hilton to write an operating system, it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML. If you have a small set of HTML pages that you want to scrape data from and then stuff into a database, regexes might work fine. Given Anne's situation this might be appropriate. As the HTML seems to be somewhat known.

Comment: My understanding of the situation is that users can type in arbitrary HTML.